# How can I sum cells that have an inexact range?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum the number of reps on the RHS as a total, taking the top value that is optional to athlete performing the set. So 8-10 appears 5 times, 50 reps total. How do I make Google Sheets do a sum for numbers such as 8-10? Is it possible?

ad

[image: cells with rep ranges in them]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. "8-10" is a text value and probably some of the alternative values are also text. I think you need a table that associates the "number of Reps" value with a number (e.g. "8-10" => 10). You need to list ALL of the "number of Reps" values and assign a number/qty for each. Then `VLOOKUP`...

Answer (score 1):

You can add these values like this:

`=sum(arrayformula(iferror(value(right(A1:E1, len(A1:E1)-find("-", A1:E1))))))`

Just change `A1:E1` to whatever range your values are in.

Below is an example of this working

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any questions, or if this does not work for you.